# How could I put a prefab into a field of a game object using editor API in Unity?

Tags: unity, editors, prefabs, api

How could I put a prefab into a field of a game object using editor API in Unity?

I have a game object. It has a `GameObject` field. I can drag and drop a prefab from my assets into that field.

Now I want to take the prefab (I have a path to it in my code) and put it into that game object field using editor API. Is it possible somehow?

I need this to automate some of my scene setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign the value in code.

`myGameObject = thingToAssign;`

You may want to do this in [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) or with [`ExecuteInEditMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html).

Comment: Yes, that worked. Also, I am creating a prefab using this api: `PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAssetAndConnect`, so I just assign the result returned by the `SaveAsPrefabAssetAndConnect`.

Comment: I got a strange behavior. Whenever I assign a property through the editor API, that property gets cleared on Play. Do you know any reasons for that? I use menu item to run an editor API code.

Comment: It could be 100 different things. Nothing particularly stands out to me. Can you ask a new question and provide as much information as you can?

Comment: Done [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/194159/after-setting-a-field-using-the-editor-api-the-field-gets-cleared-on-play-in-un).